# The continuous functions form a dense subset of $L^2$ on $[a,b]$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm confused about the first part of this proof provided on the page 327 in Rudin. In this part, we try to show characteristic functions of closed sets can be approximated in $L^2$ by continuous functions.

> Let $F$ be a closed subset of $[a,b]$, and $K_F$ its characteristics function. Put $d(X,F)=\inf_{y\in F} d(x,y)$ and $g_n(x) = \frac{1}{1+n\cdot d(x,F)}\in(0,1]$, where $n=1,2,3...$. The each $g_n$ is continuous, $g_n(x)=1$ on $F$ and $g_n(x)\to 0$ for $x\notin F$ as $n\to \infty$. Thus, $g_n\to K_F$ pointwise. So by Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem, we have $$\|g_n-K_F \| = \left( \int_a^b (g_n-K_F)^2 dx \right)^{1/2}\to 0$$. Therefore, $K_F$ is approximated in $L^2$ by a sequence $(g_n)$.

May I ask how was the Dominated Convergence Theorem applied in the above proof? I understand that $[a,b]$ is Lebesgue measurable set, and $(g_n)$ is a sequence of measurable functions in $L^2$, and $\forall x\in E, g_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$. Moreover, since $g_n(x) \le 1$, every $g_n$ is bounded above, hence the Dominated Convergence Theorem tells us that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b g_n ~dx = \int_a^b K_F~ dx.$$ It follows that $$\int_a^b g_n ~dx - \int_a^b K_F~ dx \to 0 \text{   , as $n\to 0$}.$$

But I don't now how to get to $$\left( \int_a^b (g_n-K_F)^2 dx \right)^{1/2}\to 0.$$

I tried to write $$\int_a^b g_n - K_F~ dx \to 0 \text{   , as $n\to 0$},$$ because I think this is still correct. But I couldn't convince myself that$$\int_a^b (g_n - K_F)^2~ dx \to 0 \text{   , as $n\to 0$}$$  is true as well. Because in general if I have $\int f_n \to 0$, it is not true all the time that $\int f_n^2 \to 0$ right?

Answer (score 1):

The dominated convergence theorem says that if $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $(X, F, \mu)$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $|f_n| \leq g \in L^1(X, \mu)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int f_n = \int f$. We can generalize this theorem to the following result:

Let $p \in [1, \infty)$. If $f_n$ is a sequence of measurable functions on a measure space $(X, F, \mu)$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $|f_n| \leq g \in L^p(X, \mu)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(X, \mu)$.

To prove this, we can apply the dominated convergence theorem to $|f_n - f|^p \leq (2g)^p \in L^1(X, \mu)$ to conclude that $\lim_{n \to \infty}\int|f_n - f|^p = \int 0 = 0$.

In your case, $g_n \to K_F$ pointwise and $|g_n| \leq 1 \in L^2([a, b])$, so $g_n \to K_F$ in $L^2([a, b])$.

Answer (score 0):

$0 \leq g_n \leq 1$ and $0 \leq K_F \leq 1$, so $(g_n-K_F)^{2} \leq 1$ and $1$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: Thanks I think I get it now. So we use the Dominante Convergence theorem on the sequence (g_n-K_F)^2, which converges to 0 function, and is bounded by 1. And $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int (g_n-K_F)^2 = \int 0 = 0$, and $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\int (g_n-K_F)^2)^{1/2} =0$ follows.